# Facebook posts on wordpress blog

Tags: facebook

Is there any way that i can get the facebook latest posts on to my wordpress. For example if a user types some text can clicks on the post button, then that text has to come my site...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this plugin would do the trick?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-facebook-posts/

Demo:

http://wpdemo.dannyvankooten.com/?page_id=18